# Pharo: #( $H $e $l $l $o ).'Hello' has no example in Finder

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

When I go to the finder and select "Examples" then I can't figure out how to find a method that turns `#( $H $e $l $l $o ).` into `'Hello'`. Nor does `MethodFinder new findMethodsByExampleInput: #( $H $e $l $l $o ) andExpectedResult: 'Hello'.` work.

know how to do it(*), but I want to know how to utilize the Finder.

I guess the Finder simply can't find it? Am I missing something?

(*) For example, one way to do it i: `String newFrom: #( $H $e $l $l $o ).`. Another way would be: `#($H $e $l $l $o) inject: '' into: [ :acc :el | acc, (el asString) ].` (though I would not expect the second way to be found by the Finder)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think about it like adding a collection of characters to a string rather than converting a collection to a string you can search for:

```
'' . #( $H $e $l $l $o ) . 'Hello'
```

in the Finder and you will get the results:

```
#( $H $e $l $l $o ) joinUsing: '' -> 'Hello'
'' , #( $H $e $l $l $o ) -> 'Hello'
'' join: #( $H $e $l $l $o ) -> 'Hello'
```

Comment: Code equivalent: `MethodFinder new
  findMethodsByExampleInput: {''. #( $H $e $l $l $o )}
  andExpectedResult: 'Hello'.`

Answer (score 3):

It can't find it.

Note however that there isn't a method that sent to `#($H $e $l $l $o)` would answer with `'Hello'`. What there exists is a method that sent to `String` with argument `#($H $e $l $l $o)` will answer `'Hello'`. So, the proper way to using `MethodFinder` in this case would have been

```
MethodFinder new
  findMethodsByExampleInput: {String. #( $H $e $l $l $o )}
  andExpectedResult: 'Hello'.
```

Unfortunately, the `#newFrom:` method is not explored (most class side methods aren't).